# How do I add an HTML page my front end developer built to a rails project?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Our front end developer built out an html page (our About.html page) with javascript functionality using CSS styling after given the design spec.

I have a rails project I'd like to add this page to.

I've noticed that in the rails file system, under app/views/static_pages we have 1 page, home.html.haml

I'm wondering if I should be converting this file (or files) she's built to HAML.

Comment: You don't have to convert it to haml. You can rename the home.html.haml file to home.html.erb. Then copy and paste your file there. Is the CSS embedded in the file or external?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to add the About page as a new page and not replace the existing Home page, you'll need to do the following:

1) Add a route to the new page in `routes.rb` that looks something like this:

```
get "about" => "static_pages#about"
```

2) Add a method to `app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb` that looks like this:

```
def about
end
```

3) Copy the `about.html` file to `app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work :/    Navigating to localhost:3000/about.html yielded 
  StaticPagesController#about is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the fact that this project uses haml instead of erb?

Comment: Try just `localhost:3000/about`.